# Equivalent to Arduino millis()

Tags: c, arm

I am currently working on the integration of a "shunt" type sensor on an electronic board. My choice was on a Linear (LTC2947), unfortunately it only has an Arduino driver. I have to translate everything in C under Linux to be compatible with my microprocessor (APQ8009 ARM Cortex-A7). I have a small question about one of the functions:

```
int16_t LTC2947_wake_up() //Wake up LTC2947 from shutdown mode and measure the wakeup time
{
   byte data[1];
   unsigned long wakeupStart = millis(), wakeupTime;
   LTC2947_WR_BYTE(LTC2947_REG_OPCTL, 0);
   do
   {
      delay(1);
      LTC2947_RD_BYTE(LTC2947_REG_OPCTL, data); 
      wakeupTime = millis() - wakeupStart;
      if (data[0] == 0) //! check if we are in idle mode
      {
         return wakeupTime;
      }
     if (wakeupTime > 200)
     {
  //! failed to wake up due to timeout, return -1
        return -1;
     }
   }
   while (true);
}
```

After finding usleep() as equivalent for delay(), I can not find it for millis() in C. Can you help me translate this function please?

Comment: Arduino and Linux are using *very* different paradigms.  I doubt you will achieve your goal blindly translating line by line.

Comment: @EugeneSh. is right, but see my answer below for general guidelines.

Comment: The goal is not to translate line by line, but to take the tools that interest me to recreate my function.

Answer (score 2):

Arduino `millis()` is based on a timer that trips an overflow interrupt at very close to 1 KHz, or 1 millisecond.  To achieve the same thing, I suggest you setup a timer on the ARM platform and update a `volatile unsigned long` variable with a counter.  That will be the equivalent of millis().

Here is what millis() is doing behind the scenes:

```
SIGNAL(TIMER0_OVF_vect)
{
    // copy these to local variables so they can be stored in registers
    // (volatile variables must be read from memory on every access)
    unsigned long m = timer0_millis;
    unsigned char f = timer0_fract;

    m += MILLIS_INC;
    f += FRACT_INC;
    if (f >= FRACT_MAX) {
        f -= FRACT_MAX;
        m += 1;
    }

    timer0_fract = f;
    timer0_millis = m;
    timer0_overflow_count++;
}

unsigned long millis()
{
    unsigned long m;
    uint8_t oldSREG = SREG;

    // disable interrupts while we read timer0_millis or we might get an
    // inconsistent value (e.g. in the middle of a write to timer0_millis)
    cli();
    m = timer0_millis;
    SREG = oldSREG;

    return m;
}
```

Coming from the embedded world, arguably the first thing you should do when starting a project on a new platform is establish clocks and get a timer interrupt going at a prescribed rate.  That is the "Hello World" of embedded systems.  ;)   If you choose to do this at 1 KHz, you're most of the way there.

Comment: It's has to increment a `volatile unsigned long` to be arduino compatible.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <time.h>
unsigned int millis () {
  struct timespec t ;
  clock_gettime ( CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW , & t ) ; // change CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW to CLOCK_MONOTONIC on non linux computers
  return t.tv_sec * 1000 + ( t.tv_nsec + 500000 ) / 1000000 ;
}
```

or

```
#include <sys/time.h>
unsigned int millis () {
  struct timeval t ;
  gettimeofday ( & t , NULL ) ;
  return t.tv_sec * 1000 + ( t.tv_usec + 500 ) / 1000 ;
}
```

The gettimeofday() version probably does not work on non linux computers.

The clock_gettime() version probably does not work with old C compilers.

The arduino millis() returns unsigned long, 32 bit unsigned integer.  Most
computers are 32 bit or 64 bit, so there is no need to use long except on
16 bit computers like arduino, so these versions return unsigned int.  If
you want to measure a time period longer than 50 days in milliseconds, or if
you want the number of milliseconds since the beginning of unix in 1970, you
need a long long (64 bit) integer.

If a computer clock has the incorrect time, the operating system or system
administrator or program which synchonizes the computer clock with internet
clocks may change the computer clock to the correct time.  This will affect
these functions, especially the gettimeofday() version.  Usually there is a
big change in the computer clock when the computer boots, connects to the
network, and synchonizes the computer clock with the network time server.
But most programs are not running this early in the boot process, and thus
are not affected.  Usually other changes to the computer clock are very
small, and the effect on other programs is very small.  So usually changes
to the computer clock are not a problem.

The clock_gettime() requires a clock id.

CLOCK_MONOTONIC is not affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time,
but is affected by incremental adjustments, and does not count time computer
is suspended.

CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW is linux only, not affected by discontinuous jumps in
the system time, not affected by incremental adjustments, does not count
time computer is suspended.

CLOCK_BOOTTIME is linux only, not affected by discontinuous jumps in the
system time, but is affected by incremental adjustments, does count time
computer is suspended. It counts the time since the computer booted.

CLOCK_REALTIME is affected by discontinuous jumps in the system time, and by
incremental adjustments.  It does count the time the computer is suspended.
It counts standard unix time (time since the beginning of unix in 1970).

I think CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW is the best choice for linux, and
CLOCK_MONOTONIC is the best choice for non linux.  Usually millisecond time
is used to measure short periods of time, like how long it takes for part of
a computer program to run.  In a short period of time, there will probably
be no changes to the computer clock, and the computer will probably not be
suspended, so any clock id will work, so the choice of clock id is not
important.

Precise time measurements are unreliable on multitasking computers because
the time measurement might be interrupted.  Errors are usually small.
Sometimes this is a problem, and sometimes it isn't.  If you need more
precise time measurements, you need dedicated hardware which cannot be
interrupted.  Some computers have such hardware built in.  For example, if a
program uses software pwm, changes to the output will be delayed if the
computer is interrupted at the time the computer needs to change the output.
But if the program uses hardware pwm, the hardware pwm controller cannot be
interrupted, and will change the output at the correct time.

Tested on a raspberry pi.

Comment: this is good generally, but there's no reason to add the 500ms or 500,000 ns. it adds unnecessary delay in the timestamp.

Answer (score 1):

I hope this be useful. Works for me under Lubuntu 20.04 LTS.

```
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct timeval __millis_start;

void init_millis() {
    gettimeofday(&__millis_start, NULL);
};

unsigned long int millis() {
    long mtime, seconds, useconds; 
    struct timeval end;
    gettimeofday(&end, NULL);
    seconds  = end.tv_sec  - __millis_start.tv_sec;
    useconds = end.tv_usec - __millis_start.tv_usec;

    mtime = ((seconds) * 1000 + useconds/1000.0) + 0.5;
    return mtime;
};

int main()
{
    init_millis();
    printf("Elapsed time: %ld milliseconds\n", millis());

    return 0;
}
```

**Note:**

Based on the discussion in comments (with dear @MarcCompere), I must mention that the conversion of `seconds` and `useconds` to `mtime` in the `millis` function is rounded by adding `0.5` (read comments to understand how!); but the `0.5` can be removed. It depends on your application. If you are using millis for accurate time measurement then add it to lower the "Mean Squared Error (MSE)" of conversion statistically. But if you need timing for general logic-based decisions (or closer behavior to that of Arduino), then the floor (natural behaviour when casting in this case) can be considered as the better option, so do not add the `0.5`.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: this works nicely, but there's no reason to add the 0.5 for the final mtime variable. it adds unnecessary delay in the timestamp.

Comment: @MarcCompere Hi. Thanks for checking this solution. The 0.5 is added for rounding (ceil vs floor) purpose. In this way, if the original number's partial part is less than 0.5 it'll round to 0 and if it'll round to 1, otherwise. Let me know if I'm doing a wrong thing.

Comment: hello @AbolfazlDanayi, I cannot think of a case where you want millis() to return a larger time by rounding up. the purpose of millis() is to check the time now. ceil and floor are good when rounding achieves greater accuracy. but when would a larger time be better? millis() should return the time *now* without adding delay.

Comment: @MarcCompere Hello again. Depends on our point of view about the problem. Considering the structure of a typical CPU, a timer is an up-counter (register) inside the IC which (as a  hardware unit) counts up the time with integer precision (Architectural view). On the other hand, "we are converting useconds to mseconds" thus closer the conversion, lower the error (Mathematical view). For the first view, I do support your idea and for the second view I should support initial one... In this case I will add this to the answer to clarify...